# Is there a way for GAMS interruption and re-run from where it lasted?

Tags: syntax, mathematical-optimization, gams-math, integer-programming

If I have 5 hours to wait for **GAMS** result on Monday and 3 hours on Tuesday, and if I know that the model will be solved after 8 hours first run, is there a way to interrupt GAMS on Monday after 5 hours and run again on Tuesday from where it stopped on Monday.
So, I will get result on Tuesday but totally within 8 hours.

Thanks

Comment: No, not really. Under Linux/Unix you can suspend processes. A better and simpler solution is: just run it overnight.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Erwin, I can try, however my pc is at office. But, this feature is really necessary for GAMS. Kind regards

Comment: Just run the job overnight. You don't have to sit behind your machine for it to work.